# Can blue also have a positive connotation?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I came across a statement that roughly translates as:

> I hope everything is blue with you.

The original German/English statement is:

> Ich hoffe, alles ist "blue" bei dir

This was sent to a German friend by a rather famous German sports person (J. Klinsmann, soccer) who has been living in the US for quite some time.

For me, the above expression suggests that "blue" has or is supposed to have a positive connotation, but I was unable to find any such meaning in my dictionaries.

Comment: Color has different connotations in different cultures and their attendant languages. In contemporary English, *blue* most commonly carries the sense of depressing and sad, or, less frequently, "adult" as in "adult humor". The [Wikipedia entry for color symbolism](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_symbolism) links to the [In World Culture](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue#In_world_culture) subheading in the entry for *blue*, which gives some hints as to connotations in both English and German.

Comment: @DanBron Exactly. Because the English "blue" was used in this German quote, I suppose that the intended meaning was the American one.

Comment: Could he have meant "blue" as in "blue skies"? The only contemporary American context I'm aware of where "blue" has a positive connotation, and that only indirectly, is in skydiving subculture, whose standard valediction is "*blue skies!*" (for obvious reasons). But this is like "*break a leg*" in theatre; just as in that subculture, "legs", by themselves, aren't considered lucky, so in skydiving there are no superstitions or connotations surrounding blue, qua a color.

Comment: Or is blue associated with this famous athlete's sports team in some way? Or the game itself?

Comment: @DanBron I added the sport, which is soccer. Not aware of any special meaning, but you may be right.

Comment: Ok, googling for "*j klinsmann soccer blue*" led to some interesting results. In nearly every photo of him, Klinsmann is wearing blue. Always blue. And this [New Yorker article on Klinnsman's fashion choices](http://www.newyorker.com/news/sporting-scene/klinsmanns-khakis) also suggests he has a personal preference for the color. My guess? This guy, personally, thinks blue is lucky.

Comment: @DanBron Great, I think this makes sense. So the message was essentially a private joke rather than a more widely used idiom.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my guess.

Comment: It depends on what you're into. Many people enjoy `blue movies` for example...

Answer (score 1):

*Blue* does occur in idioms that have a positive connotation: *true blue*, *blue ribbon*, *blue skies*. *Blue* can also be associated with certain, uh, adult entertainment, which depending on your attitude could be a positive. However, on its own, the color has come to be overwhelmingly associated with depression/sadness.

I think the only explanation for Herr Klinsmann's unusual wish is that he, personally, likes the color blue and has adopted it as his "signature". Or something.

Answer (score 0):

[Blue blood](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blue%20blood?s=t) (as referring to high-born people) seems to have a positive connotation, considering it is something people are proud of. (Dictionary.com)

> noun
>   1.
>   an aristocrat, noble, or member of a socially prominent family.
>   2.
>   aristocratic, noble, or socially prominent lineage or relatives:
>   They boasted a lineage of pure blue blood.